# Jboss EAP 6 CLI Script with commands that require reload

Tags: jboss, command-line-interface, jboss7.x

I'm working on a cli script for JBoss EAP 6 (just a bunch of commands in a .bat file).

Now I'm running into issues with commands that rely on each other, where the former sets the server to a "reload-required" state.

For example:

1. first command:  remove default-datasource `ExampleDS`. Outcome: success, server in state "reload required"
2. second command: remove h2-driver (required by default datasource). Outcome: failed, since server has not been restarted yet.

I've tried to place a `reload` command in between, but it seems as if the server is not completely up when the second command gets executed. Outcome still is failed, although if I try it a few seconds later, it works.

```
/subsystem=datasources/data-source=ExampleDS:remove
reload
/subsystem=datasources/jdbc-driver=h2:remove
```

Any suggestions how to make the CLI wait until JBoss is completely up again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try batching those commands together and doing a reload after you run the batch. For example:

```
batch
/subsystem=datasources/data-source=ExampleDS:remove
/subsystem=datasources/jdbc-driver=h2:remove
:reload
run-batch
```

Another option is to run the server to start the server in `admin-only` mode while configuring it. You should need the `reload` command in that case, but if you do make sure you use `:reload(admin-only=true)` until you're done configuring the server.

```
%JBOSS_HOME%\bin\standalone.bat --admin-only
rem Wait until server is started, then execute the CLI commands
%JBOSS_HOME%\bin\jboss-cli.bat -c --commands="/subsystem=datasources/data-source=ExampleDS:remove,/subsystem=datasources/jdbc-driver=h2:remove"
```